# Why doesn't GCC like this?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C and finding myself getting stuck a lot, no complains :)

Anyway, I wrote a program and GCC does not like it. The following code is NOT the program, but demonstrate the problem:

```
#define MAXLINE = 1000

int main()
{
   int tmp = MAXLINE;
   char line[MAXLINE];

   return 0;
}
```

When it is compiled, I get the following error:

> test.c:7: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token

If I replace symbolic constant MAXLINE with int 1000, everything works.

What is going on?

Answer (score 21):

When the preprocessor replaces your definition of `MAXLINE`, your code is changed to

```
int main()
{
   int tmp = = 1000;
   char line[= 1000];
   return 0;
}
```

The C preprocessor is very dumb! Do not put anything extra in your #defines (no equals, no semicolons, no nothing)

Comment: Upvoted because, unlike the rest, you explained what actually happens when you define. :-)

Comment: Agreed with Coding With Style

Answer (score 20):

Defines don't need equal signs :)

```
#define maxline 1000
```

Answer (score 10):

There shouldn't be = in define just

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
```

Comment: Beaten by 7 seconds - bad luck :(

Answer (score 3):

The `#define` statement doesn't need the equals sign.

It should read:

`#define MAXLINE 1000`

Answer (score 3):

Use **#define** without '=':

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

You shoud have

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
```

You can read more here
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object_002dlike-Macros.html#Object_002dlike-Macros

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
```